# XQuery - Including Processing Instruction

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon

I have an xml with the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MYXML>
 <?source-system-command name="abc"?>
  <NAME></NAME>
  <REQUEST>request</REQUEST>
</MYXML>
```

I want to get the REQUEST TAG  Extracted out - the Xquery is `/MYXML/REQUEST` and I get `<Request></Request>` Tag

However, now I want the REQUEST tag to be stripped off the MYXML

so the output i am looking for is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <MYXML>
     <?source-system-command name="abc"?>
      <NAME></NAME> >!-- NO REQUEST -->          
    </MYXML>
```

I wrote the following XQUERY - `"/MYXML/*[not(self::REQUEST)]"` but this filtersthe processing instruction `<?source-system-command name="abc"?>`

What am i missing ? How to tell the XQUERY Not to filter out processing instruction ?

**Using SAXON-HE 9**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `/MYXML/*[not(self::REQUEST)]` you select only element nodes so you would need at least `/MYXML/node()[not(self::REQUEST)]` or (more XPath 2/3, XQuery like and a bit closer to normal language use) `/MYXML/(node() except REQUEST)`. Note however that all those attempts only select those children of the `MYXML` root element but not that root element itself, you would need to reconstruct it with e.g.

```
<MYXML>{/MYXML/(node() except REQUEST)}</MYXML>
```

or

```
/*!element {name()} { node() except REQUEST }
```

as in https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcom